# wso2 response property to filter mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to use the Filter mediator for my response to check whether the response is a collection.

So what I did here is to check whether the element id in belongs_to_collection is a numeric

```
<property expression="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/root:movie/belongs_to_collection/id" name="collection" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<filter description="" regex="[0-9]+" source="get-property('collection')">...</filter>
```

Here's my full api config 
http://pastebin.com/QA3GCd1W

and here's the response to be filter
http://pastebin.com/0dxweJu3

Comment: Kevin, what exactly is your question?

Comment: The api configuration that I provided is not working. I also tried printing the collection property by using the Log Mediator but it doesn't show anything. '<log level="custom">
                        <property expression="get-property('collection')" name="INCOMING"/>
                    </log>

Comment: So I am having a doubt if this property is really working `<property expression="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/root:movie/belongs_to_collection/id" name="collection" scope="default" type="STRING"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to deal with namespaces, you can use `local-name()` like this.

```
<property name="collection" 
expression="//*[local-name()='belongs_to_collection']/*[local-name()='id']/text()" 
scope="default" 
type="STRING"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use namespace prefixes in your expression you need to define those namespaces. For example:

```
    <property expression="/root:movie/belongs_to_collection/id" 
name="collection" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:root="www.wso2esb.com"/>
```

The response I see when using your API however is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <jsonObject>
            <belongs_to_collection>
                <id>8650</id>
...
```

Your root element is the soapenv:Envelope tag, so you don't have to put that in your expression anymore. The / at the beginning refers to the root element. Anything after that refers to elements inside your root element.

So the expression should be as follows:

```
<property xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
name="collection" expression="/soapenv:Body/jsonObject/belongs_to_collection/id" 
scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: Another option is to use `local-name()`.